# Fail to enter suspend mode after upgrade

Tags: 18.04, suspend

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a desktop machine (8 year old). After a recent software upgrade, when I long-pressed the power button and then pressed on the suspend button, the computer failed to enter the suspend mode. The fan was still running and a running light was still on. Before the upgrade, everything was running smoothly; the fan will stop and the running light will turn blinking.

Is there anything I should configure to restore the old behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

A recent Ubuntu base update (11-Oct-2019) has solved this issue. Thanks.